# Performance penalty between using a string with GUID data or an int for a SQLite table with 20,000 rows on a phone?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that's currently using a string populated with a GUID for an PrimaryKey column on a SQLite table with 20,000 rows:

```
public class Phrase
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int PhraseNum { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My question is, for a phone application do you think it would be a good idea to not use the PhraseId which is currently a GUID and instead use the PhraseNum as the PrimaryKey? Note that I do quite a lot of look ups by PhraseId.

[image]

Comment: Any reason you don't just [go and find out](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would typically be better to use the number and even better to make the number  an alias of the rowid.

> The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing
>   one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This
>   means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. Searching
>   for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids
>   within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search
>   made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value.

[ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

You would still likely have an index (making the column UNIQUE would autogenerate an index).

As such in all likelihood you would be better off using :-

```
public class Phrase
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int PhraseNum { get; set; }
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

- Note do not use `AUTOINCREMENT` that would reduce performance.